# how to rebuild an eclipse project to recognize imported WAR file that had different version of JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

I just imported a project as a WAR file to my eclipse workspace.
the project was built on someone else's machine.
after importing it i got multiple errors, by hovering over any of them i was prompted by eclipse to downgrade to jre 1.5 (my default is 1.7)

i accepted the suggested fix, which made all errors go away except the one for the main project folder.
after searching the error i was sure it is due to the jre version.

As suggested by others i downloaded and installed JDK 5, defined it in the JAVAPATH in the environment variables and set it as default for my workspace.

i also changed the java compiler compliance level to the new version 1.5.

i also changed the execution environment to the new version.
after that i was prompted and accepted to rebuild the project. but the error didn't go a way even after restarting eclipse.

so i tried to re-rebuild it in the 1.7 jre version. but still having the same issue.

Any ideas about what is causing this issue or if am missing another step, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Point your build path jre in eclipse to jre 1.5. Right Click Project --> build path ---> libraries ---> jre (or jdk) ---> edit ---> change path to your jre 1.5

Comment: i have already done that